# Authorization information in GMail One Action API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-schemas

We are using [One Click Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action)  Email Markup in our application. We have already white-listed the email id (XXX@YYY.com) from which we are sending the emails.

The button is also shown when email is sent from the white-listed email id. But when clicked, it calls the provided service but it doesn't provide us the authorized users information eg. Bearer Token. We need that just to check whether the action was from authorized user or not. We don't fetch that person's details. Request-Response details are provided below.

URL that is called when user presses "Cancel" button
https://XXXXX.appspot.com/my/service?reqs=%5B%7B%22reqId%22%3A%20%22d690026a-1a54-de13-abf0-65c80ea0b23f%22%7D%5D

**Received Request Headers**

{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/1.0 (KHTML, like Gecko; Gmail Actions)', 'Host': 'happierhr.happierhr.appspot.com', 'X-Appengine-Region': '?', 'X-Appengine-City': '?', 'X-Appengine-Citylatlong': '0.000000,0.000000', 'Content-Type': '; charset="utf-8"', 'X-Appengine-Country': 'US'}

**Expected Request Headers**

{'Host': 'XXXXXX.appspot.com', 'Content-Type': '; charset="utf-8"', 'X-Appengine-Country': 'ZZ', 'Authorization': 'Bearer BEARER_TOKEN_FULL_STRING', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/1.0 (KHTML, like Gecko; Gmail Actions)'}

As you can see no Authorization key is being sent. Hence we are not able to authorize the user in our app. and it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running into the same issue as [30847151](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847151/gmail-action-schema-changes/31818955#31818955). You've already been whitelisted, but you will still have to request to be whitelisted for [Bearer Tokens](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens).

Comment: Thanks @Franco Now we are getting the Bearer Tokens. But we are not able to verify that. Error thrown is : AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient, https://example.com != XXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com Any ideas ?

Comment: Resolved. Instead of doing: client.verify_id_token(BEARER_TOKEN, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SERVICE_ID) Use the sender domain as the intended audience like so: client.verify_id_token(BEARER_TOKEN, "yourdomain.com") Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32379925/610940