# AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient while verifying Bearer token

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-schemas

We are using One Click Action Email Markup in our application. Our email has been white-listed the email id (XXX@YYY.com) from which we are sending the emails.

We are getting **AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient,** when we try to verify the Bearer Token. Complete stacktrace:

> File "./app/components/happier_pages/py/lib/oauth2client/util.py",
>   line 142, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) File "./app/components/happier_pages/py/lib/oauth2client/client.py", line
>   1706, in verify_id_token
>       return crypt.verify_signed_jwt_with_certs(id_token, certs, audience) File
>   "./app/components/happier_pages/py/lib/oauth2client/crypt.py", line
>   170, in verify_signed_jwt_with_certs  (aud, audience, json_body))
>   AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient, "domain.com" !=
>   "service-account-id" 
>   {"iss":"accounts.google.com","aud":"mydomain.com","sub":"1234556789","email_verified":true,"azp":"gmail@system.gserviceaccount.com","id":"123456789","verified_email":true,"email":"gmail@system.gserviceaccount.com","cid":"gmail@system.gserviceaccount.com","iat":123,"exp":123}

Below is code snippet for verifying bearer token:

```
GMAIL_ISSUEE = 'gmail@system.gserviceaccount.com'
GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SERVICE_ID = 'xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
BEARER_TOKEN=self.request.headers["Authorization"].split('Bearer ')[1]
token = client.verify_id_token(BEARER_TOKEN.strip(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SERVICE_ID)
```

The above code is extracted from [https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens](http://Documentation):

Comment: Are you literally seeing "mydomain.com" in the response token? Or are you seeing your sender domain? Because you should see your domain as the audience.

Comment: @Franco we are seeing the sender domain. But while verifying it throws `AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient`

Comment: We are seeing our sender domain.But required client service id as a audience while verifying Bearer Token.

Comment: Make sure your code follows the documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens) 

Instead of doing: 

client.verify_id_token(BEARER_TOKEN, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SERVICE_ID)

Use the sender domain as the intended audience like so:
client.verify_id_token(BEARER_TOKEN, "https://yourdomain.com")

Once you've tried that and are still running into errors, provide the trace of the new error.

Comment: @Franco Using the sender domain as the intended audience, its working fine.Thanks.

Comment: @sagar Cool man, no problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sagar has confirmed this has worked.

Instead of:

```
client.verify_id_token(BEARER_TOKEN, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SERVICE_ID)
```

Use the sender domain as the intended audience:

```
client.verify_id_token(BEARER_TOKEN, "yourdomain.com")
```